# Requiring a folder and using exports.{function}

Tags: node.js, requirejs, require

Currently I have this setup:

```
// index.js
var example = require('./folder');
```

and:

```
// folder/index.js
require('./more');

// folder/test.js
exports.thing = function() {
    console.log('test');

    return true;
}
```

But when I try in `index.js` to call `example.thing` I get:

`example.thing is not a function`

Is there any way to make it work? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory requiring is not supported by node. It requires `index.js` if it presented in the directory.

To export `thing` in `index.js` do the following:

```
// index.js
exports.thing = require('./test.js').thing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling it right? Because I tried it and it's working.

You should call it like `example.thing()` and not `example.thing`.